# Why not a private no args constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

Looking at the `ArrayUtils` class from apache commons, the doc says :

```
ArrayUtils()
```

> ArrayUtils instances should NOT be constructed in standard
>   programming.

I was looking at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.java#ArrayUtils.%3Cinit%3E%28%29) of this class, and I saw they made the constructor public :

```
public ArrayUtils() {
   super();
}
```

Since all the methods/fields of the class are static, I understand that it makes no sense to create an instance of this class.

So why don't they made the constructor `private` like in the [`Math`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Math.java) class to avoid creation of new instances?

Comment: Interestingly enough the line just below the text you quote says `This constructor is public to permit tools that require a JavaBean instance to operate.`

Comment: @fvu Wow ! I looked only at the constructor summary! Overlooked this !

Comment: It's actually funny to see a question that contains a link to its own answer gets upvoted and starred....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#ArrayUtils%28%29) says:

> This constructor is public to permit tools that require a JavaBean
>   instance to operate.

Comment: I was *seconds* from posting this exact same thing.

Comment: Still, it remains an open question what you would do with such a bean instance.

Comment: Hey, you never know when you'll need to serialize its lack of data. ;)